# Random number in c using srand and time not working

Tags: c, random, time, srand

Basically I can't figure out what's wrong here.  I'm trying randomize the two rand numbers with time, but every time I run it the same numbers show. I really can't tell what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    int i, j, m, n, primeira, tipo, orient;
    int matrix[10][20];
    time_t tempo = time(NULL);

    printf("Enter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter number of columns : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /* first input */
    printf("1 ou 0");
    scanf("%d", &primeira);
    if (primeira == 0) {
      matrix [0][0]=0;
      matrix [0][1]=0;
      matrix [0][2]=0;
      matrix [1][0]=0;
      matrix [1][1]=0;
      matrix [1][2]=0;
      matrix [2][0]=0;
      matrix [2][1]=3;
      matrix [2][2]=0;
    }
    else
    {
        srand(tempo);
        tipo = rand() % 9;
        orient = rand() % 4;
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] with input used.

Comment: Make sure the program only calls `srand()` once in the lifetime of the program.

Comment: That snippet of code looks OK. It should work and not re-regenerate random values.